# Using an sql join's "ON" statement with an "AND" instead of a "WHERE"

Tags: sql, oracle, join

So I'm wondering which one is best performance wise and also if using an AND is simply bad practice here.

Compare the two following queries ends :

Using a "WHERE" at the end :

```
select c.cust_last_name,
       o.order_total,
       oi.quantity
from   customers c 
       join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.customer_id)
       join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_id)
where  c.GENDER='M';
```

Using an "AND" at the end :

```
select c.cust_last_name,
       o.order_total,
       oi.quantity
from   customers c 
       join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.customer_id)
       join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_id and c.GENDER='M');
```

The and is riding on the last ON's conditions to retrieve the exact same dataset as the first query. Is this OK?

Comment: I would move the `c.GENDER = 'M'` condition one level higher, on the first `JOIN`, since that's where it's part of, logically.

Comment: It would make semantic difference if using outer join. From performance perspective, there is no difference. Oracle is able to transform one query into the other. Both will have the same exec plan.

Comment: You're right about the exec plan remaining the same I just checked it and oracle interprets it the exact same way indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, I doubt it would make much difference to Oracle which version of the query you used. You could check by looking at the explain plan for each query.

However, it is only "safe" to move the `c.gender = 'M'` predicate into the join condition here because you're doing an inner join. If you were doing an outer join, you'd see different results depending on whether that predicate was in the where or join clause.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference whether to put the condition in the WHERE clause or an ON clause.

But yes, what you show *is* bad practise, because `and c.GENDER='M'` has nothing to do with which records to join from table `order_items`. The criteria in an ON clause should always belong with its table.

An example with additional criteria on the order items table would be

```
join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_id and and oi.price > 50)
```

Here it is more or less a matter of personal preference if you want to see this in the ON clause or WHERE clause. You could argue that you join the tables on their order IDs and then only *keep* results with a price higher then 50, so the join is on the IDs only. Or you could argue that you *join* order items with a price > 50. Both statements are semantically correct.

However it is a good habit to always have all criteria on a table in its ON clause. When you change

```
inner join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_id)
where oi.price > 50
```

to

```
left join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_id)
where oi.price > 50
```

this is effectively an inner join still, because the outer-joined records will have a price of NULL which doesn't meet your WHERE clause criteria so you'd remove the records right after creating them :-) So you would have to move the criteria to the ON clause because of the other join type. Wouldn't it be better to have it there already?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a difference in performance which is not much significant unless you have a big amount of records in your tables.

The first case is first getting all the relevant records according to the inner join and then filtering according to male gender. You are loading all the records which part of them are not relevant (female) and then filtering.

In the second case, the non-relevant records will not be gathered at all, the filtering is done as part of the join operation.

And I agree with @Radu Gheorghiu, you may want to move c.GENDER = 'M' condition one level higher.